# Robot.keypress and Robot.keyrelease acts weird

Tags: java, android, key, simulator, game-physics

I am trying to control games from my android phone and I have an issue.
If I press any of the `wasd` keys and I try putting the input into a text editor, there is no problem. Whether it is the browser, notepad or the ide itself, it works.
However, when I tried it in games ( I tried minecraft and urban terror ), nothing happens.

Did anyone have this issue, do you have any idea how to deal with this?

The client code looks like

```
if(parts[1].equals("FWD") ) { //we send the string "FWD" from the phone when key 'W' is pressed

                try{
                    Robot robo=new Robot();
                    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                }
                catch (AWTException e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }

            }
```

Comment: You are passing keypress and keyrelease to Robot class, so what it will do it will print that character if notepad is opened. But in case of Game you need to pass the robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.KeyEvent.VK_W) and after some time KeyRelease(); then only you can predict the forward motion. For that you need to pass two messages from android App, on key press and on key release.

Comment: Yes, and it does the print the character in notepad and any other text input. However it is not perceived by the games

Comment: If you do like this   try{
                    Robot robo=new Robot();
                    robo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                    robo.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);
                }     you can't predict the motion, because it is a sudden keypress and keyRelease.

Comment: yeah, but I fire an event at a few miliseconds and it changes the value of parts[1] and the code is event is triggered

Comment: say I continuously press the 'W' key and this event is seen and interpreted. This works if I focus on a text editor. Press the 'w' on the phone and I don't release the key, and the input will continuously get the 'w'. This works